# How to block everything except http(s) and DNS in iptables?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall

I want to setup firewall on my Ubuntu machine, to specifically block everything in and out except ports 80/443 for browsing, and 53 for resolving DNS, I tried but no result.

Now Im using `UFW` which is easy to setup but I'm not sure if it's safe as `iptables`.
Can someone answer me how to block every port except those needed?

Comment: The default `deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)` should do fine. Ports 80/443 are privileged ports that are only relevant if you are running a web **server**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you should know, `ufw` itself is somehow a front-end for `iptables`, it's a program for managing a netfilter firewall.

If you are not really good at using `iptables` I strongly suggest using `ufw` instead. you can even use `gufw`, a graphical interface to use `ufw` even easier than it's already is.

#### Is `ufw` safe?

I can assure you that by using `ufw` you are safe, because it's the same thing with a lot of predefined and reliable rules to protect your machine.

By default it's allow outgoing connections and denies incoming ones, so for example no one can `ssh` into your machine.

Lets have a look around:

First make sure `ufw` is disabled:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Now lets remove all iptables chains and rules:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
```

And use `iptables -L` to have look at default `iptables` chains and rules, which should be three chain and all of them are accepting everything.

lets enable `ufw`:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Now if you have a look at `iptables` rules using `iptables -L`, you will see a lot of rules has been set by `ufw` to protect you, which they are good enough to relay on.

Also, if you run: `sudo ufw status verbose`, you'll get a simple output that tells you whats going on:

```
Status: active
Logging: off
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
```

---

#### How to block everything except http(s) & DNS using iptables?

If you insist to use `iptables`, first disable `ufw` then remove all chains and rules using `-F` and `-X` switches.

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
```

**Policies:**
Then we should set policies. policies are default behavior, when a packet does not match to any rules that been defined, these policies will be applied on them:

```
sudo iptables -P DROP INPUT
sudo iptables -P DROP OUTPUT
sudo iptables -P DROP FORWARD
```

Then to allow outgoing DNS:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

And to allow outgoing http(s):

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Finally, we are going to only allow related and established incoming traffics:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Yes I know ufw is front-end for iptables but I see a lot of rules and I dont know what they deny or allow.Now im sure its safe as you said.I will try iptables to see what happens thanks!!!